# How to set a variable to implementations of generic typed Trait in rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am new to rust and I am trying to write an app that basically uses one of many possible services to fetch some data, transform it and save to my database.

I am trying to do something like a generic interface from Java, to instantiate the correct service based on command line input and use it throughout the program.

I have coded something like this:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;

pub trait Service<T> {
    fn get_values(&self, id: u64) -> T;
    fn convert_data(&self, input: T, output: &mut Vec<MyDataStruct>) -> Result<String>;
}
```

and two different implementations:

```rust
struct ServiceA {
    clientA: DataRetrieverForA,
}

struct ServiceB {
    clientB: DataRetrieverForB,
}

impl Service<Result<ADataStruct>> for ServiceA {
    fn get_values(&self, id: u64) -> Result<ADataStruct>;
    fn convert_data(&self, input: Result<ADataStruct>, output: &mut Vec<MyDataStruct>) -> Result<String>;
}

impl Service<BDataStruct> for ServiceB {
    fn get_values(&self, id: u64) -> BDataStruct;
    fn convert_data(&self, input: BDataStruct, output: &mut Vec<MyDataStruct>) -> Result<String>;
}
```

the `self.get_values(id)` uses the `self.clientX` to retrieve data and `self.convert_data(input, &mut output)` transforms data from `ADataStruct` and `BDataStruct` to `MyDataStruct` before saving it to my database.

The app will run using either `ServiceA` or `ServiceB` depending on command line input:

```rust
fn main() {
    // ...

    let service: Box<&(dyn Service<_>)> = match cli_service {
        Service::A => { Box::new(&ServiceA::new(...) }
        Service::B => { Box::new(&ServiceB::new(...) }
    };

    //...
}
```

I have tried many changes, mostly based on https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html and https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html but I can't find an example that handles functions that use a generic type from trait definition. When I removed the generic  parameter and fixed it to some common struct for testing, the code compiled and ran with no errors. So my guess is my mistake is with generic/trait usage.

The error I get with this code:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ServiceB: Service<ADataStruct>` is not satisfied
  --> ori-runner\src\main.rs:40:37
   |
40 | ... { Box::new(&ServiceB::new(params)...
   |       -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Service<ADataStruct>` is not implemented for `ServiceB`
   |       |
   |       required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <ServiceB as Service<BDataStructure>>
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Service<ADataStruct>>`
```

What am I doing wrong? It is obvious the first match type is defining the '_' of the dyn Service variable, but I am out of ideas and google searches...

Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that your pointer should use the same type signature, `Box<dyn Service<SOME_TYPE>>`, SOME_TYPE is different for your implementations, so it is never gonna compile.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. But if every service would return something different, which approach should I use then? I thought the _ was like a ? in java. If I can't use Generic typed traits to define method signatures, wouldn't they be useless? I feel I am missing something here...

Comment: if each service doesnt use the same data you cannot do it in this way.

Comment: Understood. Would you have a suggestion to give me? I would appreciate it if you could point me to some direction on how to implement this.

Comment: One possible solution is to put the rest of your `main` in a helper function/struct that is generic over a service (`<T, S: Service<T>>`) and then call the helper with the appropriate `Service` type based on the value of `cli_service`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the types are different, one option would be to wrap them in an `enum` and have some method/s for computing whatever needed depending on the decision. The enum wrapper would abstract the services operations.

```rust
struct DataRetrieverForA {}
struct DataRetrieverForB {}

struct ADataStruct {}
struct BDataStruct {}
struct MyDataStruct {}

struct ServiceA {
    clientA: DataRetrieverForA,
}

struct ServiceB {
    clientB: DataRetrieverForB,
}

impl ServiceA {
    fn get_values(&self, id: u64) -> Result<ADataStruct, ()> {
        Ok(ADataStruct {})
    }
    fn convert_data(
        &self,
        input: Result<ADataStruct, ()>,
        output: &mut Vec<MyDataStruct>,
    ) -> Result<String, ()> {
        Ok("foo".into())
    }
}

impl ServiceB {
    fn get_values(&self, id: u64) -> BDataStruct {
        BDataStruct {}
    }
    fn convert_data(
        &self,
        input: BDataStruct,
        output: &mut Vec<MyDataStruct>,
    ) -> Result<String, ()> {
        Ok("bar".into())
    }
}

enum Services {
    A(ServiceA),
    B(ServiceB),
}

impl Services {
    fn a() -> Self {
        Self::A(ServiceA {
            clientA: DataRetrieverForA {},
        })
    }

    fn b() -> Self {
        Self::B(ServiceB {
            clientB: DataRetrieverForB {},
        })
    }

    fn compute(self) {
        todo!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arg = "a";

    let service = match arg {
        "a" => Services::a(),
        _ => Services::b(),
    };
    service.compute();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5e527f49fa6a9c0f52c85f2923bf9aee)

Comment: I am trying this approach, thanks for your example. How would I get access to get_values and convert_data service methods from the enum's compute function?

Comment: you would have to match the enum: `match self {...}`